# Using clone jQuery function needing to create dynamic input names

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a HTML form as follows which I have condensed to get to the point of what I need help with.

```
<div id="outsider-wrapper">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <form>
        <input name="var[][name]" />
        <input name="var[][size]" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also have a link that invokes the following JS.

```
$('#link'.click(function(){
    $('#wrapper').clone().appendTo('#outside-wrapper');
});
```

At the moment, this allows multiple forms to be added on the fly. My issue comes when I deal with the data in the backend, I need to be able to return errors into the form values so I need to be able to count the `var[]` with the clone function. As the extra forms are generated on the fly, how could I get them to remain in place when the page is reloaded?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried?

Comment: This simply means "I haven't tried anything".

Comment: `$('#morebtn').click(function(){$('input[type="submit"]').before('<input type="text" name="title[]" /><input type="text" name="description[]" />');});`

Comment: Thanks for the input Russell :) It's not so much the JS to add the fields, more to create a loop so that the title and description are an array within a master array. So each time I click the 'add' button, another title and description is added.

Comment: Reworded the question to be more specific to what I need help with!

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<form>
<button>Add</button><button type="submit>Save</button>
<input type="text" name="items[][title]" />
<input type="text" name="items[][description]" />
</form>
```

js

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $('form').append('<br /><input type="text" name="items[][title]" /><input type="text" name="items[][description]" />')
})
```

Once these are submitted you should end up with something like this in your parameters

```
{items: [
    {title: 'title1', description: 'description1'},
    {title: 'title2', description: 'description2'}
]}
```

You can get more complicated with it but this basic design can be scaled near infinitely.

Comment: Ahhh so using this, the items array would contain an array for each title and description? I could then count the items array and loop through and use the data? Perfect!

Comment: I think were saying the same thing here but to clarify.  You end with an array of hashes.  Each hash in the array contains a key for title and description.  So iterating through each can be done with a loop where the local variable would be a hash similar to this: {title: 'title1', description: 'description1'}.

Answer (score 0):

The code to add the elements is pretty basic. Here is an example based on your HTML-

```
$('some_element').click(function() {
    var stuffToAdd = '<br /><input type="text" name="title[]" /><br /><input type="text" name="description[]" />';
    $('input[name="description"]:last').after(stuffToAdd);
});
```

Using `after()` will place the new elements as the last elements in the form prior to the submit button. Adding the brackets after the title and description will make these post as arrays which you should then be able to extract on the server-side for processing.